# How to style GridView item background using selection checkbox?

Tags: wpf, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I would like to style my GridviewItem PointerOverBackground and SelectedPointerOverBackground background color. Problem is, when i use the default checkbox for selection, the background becomes black/transparent and only the border is visible.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oeryt.png)

```
<GridView x:Name="PhotostreamList" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewItemContainerStyle}" IsMultiSelectCheckBoxEnabled="{Binding SelectionMode}" SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemsSource="{Binding PhotoList}" SelectionChanged="PhotostreamList_SelectionChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Left" RightTapped="PhotostreamList_RightTapped" >
```

I'm using the following Style for this:

```
    <Style x:Key="GridViewItemContainerStyle" TargetType="GridViewItem">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource GridViewItemBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource GridViewItemForeground}"/>
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
        <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,4,4"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource GridViewItemMinWidth}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource GridViewItemMinHeight}"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-2"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualPrimaryBrush" Value="{ThemeResource GridViewItemFocusVisualPrimaryBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualPrimaryThickness" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualSecondaryBrush" Value="{ThemeResource GridViewItemFocusVisualSecondaryBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualSecondaryThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewItem">
                    <ListViewItemPresenter 
                        CheckBrush="{ThemeResource GridViewItemCheckBrush}" 
                        ContentMargin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                        CheckMode="{ThemeResource GridViewItemCheckMode}" 
                        ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" 
                        CheckBoxBrush="{ThemeResource GridViewItemCheckBoxBrush}" 
                        DragForeground="{ThemeResource GridViewItemDragForeground}" 
                        DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" 
                        DragBackground="{ThemeResource GridViewItemDragBackground}" 
                        DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"
                        Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True" 
                        PointerOverForeground="{ThemeResource GridViewItemForegroundPointerOver}" 
                        PressedBackground="{ThemeResource GridViewItemBackgroundPressed}" 
                        PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource GridViewItemPlaceholderBackground}" 
                        PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource GridViewItemBackgroundPointerOver}" 
                        ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource GridViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" 
                        SelectedPressedBackground="{ThemeResource GridViewItemBackgroundSelectedPressed}" 
                        SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="{ThemeResource GridViewItemSelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled}" 
                        SelectedForeground="{ThemeResource GridViewItemForegroundSelected}" 
                        SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource GridViewItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver}" 
                        SelectedBackground="{ThemeResource GridViewItemBackgroundSelected}" 
                        VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

What i found is, when i set the "CheckMode" from "Inline" to "Overlay" i get this: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVV8D.png)

I found no way to fill the background in "Inline" mode so how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by copying the "GridViewItemExpanded" Style into my project from:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.14393.0\Generic\generic.xaml

This style contains the whole ControlTemplate with checkbox and i was able to make changes to the background.